# How to fix eclipselink setup

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I'am currently working with eclipselink and after pulling the Project on another PC all parts of eclipselink, for example EntityManagerFactory are marked as an error. In the build.gradle there is a dependencie for eclipselink and it is running fine. The only issue is that the IDE marks it as an error. Any Ideas how to fix this?

I tried pulling again and restarted the IDE. So far i did not change anything on the gradle files since they are working on other PCs.

compile 'org.eclipse.persistence:eclipselink:2.6.4'

Comment: Maybe if you tell us which IDE you are using we can help you

Comment: I am using eclipse

Comment: After 1 Year i still have the same issue so if anyone sees this, pls answere even though it is kinda old.